# Correctly indexing a multidimensional Numpy array with another array of indices

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to index a multidimensional array `P` with another array `indices`. which specifies which element along the last axis I want, as follows:

```
import numpy as np

M, N = 20, 10

P = np.random.rand(M,N,2,9)

# index into the last dimension of P
indices = np.random.randint(0,9,size=(M,N))

# I'm after an array of shape (20,10,2)
# but this has shape (20, 10, 2, 20, 10)
P[...,indices].shape
```

How can I correctly index `P` with `indices` to get an array of shape `(20,10,2)`?

If that's not too clear: For any `i` and `j` (in bounds) I want `my_output[i,j,:]` to be equal to `P[i,j,:,indices[i,j]]`

Comment: I am probably being slow, but how can you use a 2D array to index along one axis ("the last axis" in your question)? Surely, indexing along a single axis requires one coordinate and not two?

Comment: I didn't explain it very well, which may well be related to why I am stuck here. For any `i` and `j` I want `my_output[i,j,:]` to be equal to `P[i,j,:,indices[i,j]]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
P[np.arange(M)[:, None, None], np.arange(N)[:, None], np.arange(2),
  indices[..., None]]
```

Not pretty, I know...

---

This may look nicer, but it may also be less legible:

```
P[np.ogrid[0:M, 0:N, 0:2]+[indices[..., None]]]
```

or perhaps better:

```
idx_tuple = tuple(np.ogrid[:M, :N, :2]) + (indices[..., None],)
P[idx_tuple]
```