# NumPy: How to collapse N-dimensional array along a single dimension using argmin/max output?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, matrix, numpy, slice

Is there a straight-forward way to use the output of calling NumPy's `argmax` or `argmin` functions on a single dimension of an N-D array to define an index into that array?

This is probably best explained with an example. Consider the following example
 of a 2D grid of readings of temperature across time:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> times = np.array([0, 20])
>>> temperature_map_t0 = np.array([[10, 12, 14], [23, 40, 50]])
>>> temperature_map_t1 = np.array([[20, 12, 15], [23, 10, 12]])
>>> temperature_map = np.dstack([temperature_map_t0, temperature_map_t1])
```

and identically shaped N-D array containing a corresponding *pressure* readings:

```
>>> pressure_map = np.random.rand(*temperature_map.shape)
```

We can find the top temperatures at each location:

```
>>> top_temperatures = temperature_map.max(axis=2)
>>> top_temperatures
array([[20, 12, 15],
       [23, 40, 50]])
```

and the times at which they occurred:

```
>>> times = times[temperature_map.argmax(axis=2)]
>>> times
array([[20,  0, 20],
       [ 0,  0,  0]])
```

But how can we use `temperature_map.argmax(axis=2)` to find the corresponding
 pressures?

```
>>> pressures_at_top_temperatures = pressures[ ???? ]
```

In other words - what is the indexing syntax to collapse a single dimension of
 an N-D array using the `argmin` or `argmax` indices for that dimension?

Comment: Almost identical (if I'm reading your question correctly):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469302/numpy-3d-to-2d-transformation-based-on-2d-mask-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to [Jaime](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110026/jaime) who answered when I had a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15661214/553404)

```
import numpy as np
times = np.array([0, 20])
temperature_map_t0 = np.array([[10, 12, 14], [23, 40, 50]])
temperature_map_t1 = np.array([[20, 12, 15], [23, 10, 12]])
temperature_map = np.dstack([temperature_map_t0, temperature_map_t1])
top_temperatures = temperature_map.max(axis=2)

# shape is a tuple - no need to convert
# http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html
pressure_map = np.random.rand(*temperature_map.shape)

idx = temperature_map.argmax(axis=2)

s = temperature_map.shape
result pressure_map[np.arange(s[0])[:, None], np.arange(s[1]), idx]
```

Comment: @Mr.E -- There's an answer to my very similar question which I think is slighly nicer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15469302/numpy-3d-to-2d-transformation-based-on-2d-mask-array

Comment: @mgilson, yeah that is nice. I hadn't come across ndenumerate before. Thanks - you should post an answer (or vote to close?)

Comment: I was actually referring to the answer which uses `ogrid`

Answer (score 0):

The most straight-forward solution I could think of was to use logical indexing to zero out the entries that are not selected by the desired index, and then to sum over the dimension of interest, e.g. as follows:

```
def collapse_dimension(ndarr, index, axis):
    r = np.rollaxis(ndarr, axis, 0)
    return np.sum((r[i] * (index == i) for i in range(r.shape[0])), axis=0)
```

So given the above example, we can use `argmax` or `argmin` to collapse the array on any given dimension, e.g.

```
>>> pressures_at_top_temperatures = collapse_dimension(
...     pressure_map, temperature_map.argmax(axis=2), 2)
```

and, trivially, get the `max` across any given dimension using the corresponding `argmax`:

```
>>> temperature_map.max(axis=2) == collapse_dimension(
...     temperature_map, temperature_map.argmax(axis=2), 2)
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

However, I have a strong suspicion there's a nicer way to do this that doesn't involve writing this extra function -- any ideas??